# create my own directory in html with download links

Tags: html-table

I was trying to create an online webshare but i'm unable to make a page which will automatically add or remove files from the site when done so. Please help me in resolving this problem. And I'm not able to link the PHP code to  the html page to execute, please help me in creating the html and PHP in my already built design pages so that i can complete my project.
**The Php Of The Page Goes As Follows**

```html
<html>
    <body style="background:#e9e9e9; font-family:Verdana; font-size:180%">
<head>
    <p style="text-align:center; size:20%">Download Now&#33;
    <br>No Need of Internet&#33;</p>
    </head>
    <div style="background:white; margin-right:2%; margin-left:2%; font-size:150%">
        <font color="cornflowerblue">Owais</font> shared some files with you.
        <hr>
        Files
        <hr>
<?php
  if ($handle = opendir('C:\Users\makro\Documents\Share\Send')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
      if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        $thelist .= '<li><a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';
      }
    }
    closedir($handle);
  }
?> 
<h1>List of files:</h1>
<ul><?php echo $thelist; ?></ul>
        </div>
        </body>
</html>
```